# ajax jquery struts2 list of objects (which contains list of objects internally)

Tags: jquery, ajax, struts2

Using jQuery ajax when click on "Next" I will get list of objects (which contains list of objects internally) without converting that to json and not using any other plugin, how I can render this list to display the table similar to  in struts.

Currently I am using a include jsp with only the table to be refreshed with next set of results and replacing the existing table div with new jsp. Can someone suggest any other method to do this.

List of Orders and each order has multiple items. One row represents

```
Order#  --  Order Date -- Item# -- Item Description

                            1   --  Shirt
1       --  05/21/2012 --   2   --  Pant
                            3   --  Brief
```

If I have 100 orders per page if I display 25 Orders when I click on "NEXT" button as explained above I will get list of next 25 orders then it should display the next 25.

Comment: Someone might be able to figure out what exactly you're dealing with, but the rest of us will need more detail (preferably some sample data and/or some code).

Comment: I have modified, let me know if I need to provide more info.

Comment: You need ajax, but can't use json and you want the data to present a list which may include as one of it's elements an other list, which you need to render on the client side? The only sensible answer then is XML (possibly a block of html would do). However because you have not specified a reason not to use json, I'm supposing you think it's complicated...  you're in for a surprise if you think XML will be less complicated! If your question requires an explanation for the full round trip including storage and other details, then the scope is too large and there is no tractable answer.

Comment: Replace a div/span's contents with rendered HTML; what do you believe the other options to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used the [.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function to refresh the list. Same as given example, No conversion to Json is required.

Action Class

```
public String 25Orders(){
// get from DB 25 orders
// on Click of next by passing page 2 get next 25 orders
}

public Map<abc, Lis<xyz>> getOrders(){
return objects;
}
```

.js class

```
$("a[id=pagination]").click(function(event) {
     $("div").load("fulord",{pageStr:this.name});
});
```

jsp class

```
<div id=OrdersTable>
<s:iterator value="Orders">
   <tr>
     <td><s:property value=key.orderNumber/></td>
     <td><s:property value=key.orderDate/></td>
      <td>
        <table> 
           <s:iterator value=items>
            <tr>
             <td><s:property value=itemNumber/></td>
             <td><s:property value=itemDesc/></td>
            </tr>
           </s:iterator>
         </table>
      </td>
   </tr>
</s:iterator>
</div>
```

**NOTE:**
But I see one problem here if a page has more than one div or if I try to give div ID in js it won't work properly. I am trying to resolve that but as of this is solution I found.